# Android app skipping frames and hanging delay with imageviews

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, imageview

I've created a flashlight app for android which generally runs fine aside from a couple of issues:

- When the app first turns on a grey background appears for around 1 second then my app starts, this grey background is nowhere in my app code.
- The app has two button imageviews which when clicked switch on the flashlight and change the imageview to the other button state. The app works quick when switching from off state to on, but when going from on to off there is a noticeable one second delay.
- Around 31-35 frames are skipped when I press the button to switch from on to off which is where the delay occurs though no skipped frames when switching from off to on.

I've been searching for the solution for around 2 days scanning through systrace and modifying my code but can't seem to figure it out. The application is pretty simple with all the Camera work done using AsyncTask for opening camera and a separate AsyncTask for closing the camera.

Here is my Activity java file:

- http://pastebin.com/XVmvZk1N

Here is my Activity xml file:

- http://pastebin.com/xxPkuVSA

Here is the systrace log:

- http://pastebin.com/v41CPs5X

I would appreciate any help with these issues.

Thank you.